# How to define DT_RowIndex using DataTable files yajra on Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, datatable, yajra-datatable

I have a problem defining DT_RowIndex using the file datatable yajra on laravel 9, i don't want to use the id of the table. iwant to defining number of row with pagination table on the datatable.
this is the file on datatable

```
<?php

namespace App\DataTables;

use App\Models\User;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Button;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Column;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Editor\Editor;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Editor\Fields;
use Yajra\DataTables\Services\DataTable;

class UsersDataTable extends DataTable
{

    public function dataTable($query)
    {
        return datatables()
            ->eloquent($query)
            ->editColumn('actions', function ($data) {
                return "<a href=".route('users.edit', $data->id) . " class='btn btn-primary btn-sm'>
                Edit
            </a> <button class='delete btn btn-danger btn-sm' onclick='deleteFunc(". $data->id .")'> Delete </button>";
            })
            ->rawColumns(['actions']);
    }

    public function query(User $model)
    {
        return $this->applyScopes($model->query());
    }

    public function html()
    {
        return $this->builder()
                    ->setTableId('usersdatatable-table')
                    ->columns($this->getColumns())
                    ->minifiedAjax()
                    ->dom('Bfrtip')
                    ->orderBy(1)
                    ->buttons(
                        Button::make('create'),
                        Button::make('export'),
                        Button::make('print'),
                        Button::make('reset'),
                        Button::make('reload')
                    );
    }


    protected function getColumns()
    {
        return [
            Column::make('no')
                ->addIndexColumn(true),
            Column::make('name'),
            Column::computed('actions')
                ->exportable(false)
                ->printable(false)
                ->width(200)
                ->addClass('text-center'),
        ];
    }

    protected function filename() : string
    {
        return 'Users_' . date('YmdHis');
    }
}
```

so How to defining the code of DT_RowIndex on that's file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an index column on your response by using `addIndexColumn` API/method

based on your code:

```
public function dataTable($query)
{
    return datatables()
        ->eloquent($query)
        ->addIndexColumn()
        ->editColumn('actions', function ($data) {
            return "<a href=".route('users.edit', $data->id) . " class='btn btn-primary btn-sm'>
            Edit
        </a> <button class='delete btn btn-danger btn-sm' onclick='deleteFunc(". $data->id .")'> Delete </button>";
        })
        ->rawColumns(['actions']);
}
```

Using `addIndexColumn` will add another column on your response with a column name that is set on `index_column` configuration. The default index column name is `DT_RowIndex`.

reference: https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/index-column